# Convert Audio file into MP3 format using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, audio

is there any way to convert all type of audio files into MP3 format.
in my website... i have one control which plays MP3 files[audio]. but i have to provide facility to upload any kind of audio file[as i am developing audio gallary] and play it in my website..

if there is better solution to upload and play audio files in the website developed using asp.net 3.5
then also please reply.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56573987/m4a-audio-file-convert-to-flac-c-sharp/56582913#56582913

Answer (score 8):

1. You can either use [LAME](http://lame.sourceforge.net/) to run
   outside of your application (a very
   good compressor), for which [an
   example is here](http://vinothnat.blogspot.com/2007/11/convert-wav-to-mp3-using-lameexe-in-c.html). This will work
   very well, but you might get
   problems with it on a webserver. It
   would be best to host a service for
   this action, and have the page post
   items to a queue.
2. Or you can use one
   of the many libraries that already
   exist, [like this one](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/MP3Compressor.aspx) for
   example. This still runs LAME, but it uses the DLL instead.

Comment: +1 for considering using a message queue if you need to consider scalability in the future.

Comment: hi Codesleuth thanks for help... but does LAME converts Midi files into mp3 formats?? coz have converted wmv, wave files into mpe using ffmpeg as i am using same for video conversion also... 

the example for which you provide me link, show only how to convert wav into mp3 format... but i need to support .midi, .mpeg, .wav, .mp4 and .mp3 files in my site. so can you suggest me any resource to convert midi file into mp3 format using c#?

Comment: Since MIDI files are records of scores and not audio, you will need to use a renderer. There's another question on S.O. about it (with a solution) here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185392/how-to-convert-midi-to-wav-mp3-in-c
Remember that not all audio files contain PCM or compressed PCM data - you will need to perform a lot of legwork to get "all types" of audio files as mp3.

Answer (score 1):

```
static void AnyToMp3(string fileName)
{
    DsReader dr = new DsReader(fileName);
    IntPtr formatPcm = dr.ReadFormat();
    byte[] dataPcm = dr.ReadData();
    dr.Close();
    IntPtr formatMp3 = AudioCompressionManager.GetCompatibleFormat(formatPcm,
        AudioCompressionManager.MpegLayer3FormatTag);
    byte[] dataMp3 = AudioCompressionManager.Convert(formatPcm, formatMp3, dataPcm, false);
    Mp3Writer mw = new Mp3Writer(File.Create(fileName + ".mp3"));
    mw.WriteData(dataMp3);
    mw.Close();
}
```

from [Is it possible for converting any audio file to mp3?](http://alvas.net/alvas.audio,tips.aspx#tip93)

Comment: Note this is a commercial solution requiring licenses.