# How to convert any audio format to MP3 using C#

Tags: c#

I want to play the audio uploaded by the users. The uploaded audio will be in any format.
Is there a way to convert any audio file into mp3 format?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert Audio file into MP3 format using C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324926/convert-audio-file-into-mp3-format-using-c-sharp)

Answer (score 6):

You can use this function - based on `alvas component`

Link : http://alvas.net/alvas.audio,tips.aspx#tip24

```
private void ConvertAudio()
    {
        string webFile = @"D:\AudioCS\bin\Debug\_web.mp3";
        string pcmFile = @"D:\AudioCS\bin\Debug\_AudioCS.wav";
        using (WaveReader wr = new WaveReader(File.OpenRead(pcmFile)))
        {
            IntPtr pcmFormat = wr.ReadFormat();
            byte[] pcmData = wr.ReadData();
            IntPtr webFormat = AudioCompressionManager.GetCompatibleFormat(pcmFormat,
            AudioCompressionManager.MpegLayer3FormatTag);
            byte[] webData = AudioCompressionManager.Convert(pcmFormat, webFormat,
            pcmData, false);
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

            using (WaveWriter ww = new WaveWriter(ms,
            AudioCompressionManager.FormatBytes(webFormat)))
            {
                ww.WriteData(webData);
                using (WaveReader wr2 = new WaveReader(ms))
                {
                    using (FileStream fs = File.OpenWrite(webFile))
                    {
                        wr2.MakeMP3(fs);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you but I am not able to convert ogg file into mp3.

Comment: Use DsReader instead of WaveReader. See http://alvas.net/alvas.audio,tips.aspx#tip55