# m4a audio file convert to flac c#

Tags: c#, google-cloud-speech

I have been searching for the C# library or code sample which could help me to do the conversion of `m4a` audio file to `flac`, but more importantly with sample rate (of 16000), mono channel and bit resolution of either 16 or 24.

Right now, I have found library solutions like `NAudio, MediaToolKit and SOXSharp`. But I cannot get enough information how to use them accordingly.

I needed those converted audio files for Google Cloud speech to text API inputs.

I have found [this great website](https://audio.online-convert.com/convert-to-flac) where I can convert files manually and they are working great with API.

Is there any C# library which can help to convert .M4A audio file to .FLAC?

Comment: downvoters and close request maker can explain the act, so that i can update question?

Comment: the question not clear

Comment: @FerasAlSous i have explain the reasons, and updated the question. Thanks for point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue with library [FFMpeg.Net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/xFFmpeg.NET/) and [FFMpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/).

Install on windows guide [here](http://blog.gregzaal.com/how-to-install-ffmpeg-on-windows/).

and then in code

```
var inputFile = new MediaFile (@"C:\file.m4a");
var outputFile = new MediaFile (@"C:\file.flac");

var ffmpeg = new Engine("C:\\ffmpeg\\ffmpeg.exe");
await ffmpeg.ConvertAsync(inputFile, outputFile);
```

Beware there might be file write permission denied error when writing to `c://` and `windows environment variable`.